# Search eBay using the API from R

Tags: r, ebay-api

I'm trying to use R to conduct searches in eBay on the site's API.  However, I'm at a complete loss as to how to do this.

I'm familiar with using other APIs in R, e.g. Twitter and Instagram.  Some of these searches can be conducted using dedicated libraries (twitteR, streamR, etc.), but I've also had to cobble stuff together with httr and RCurl.  Unfortunately, I'm having absolutely no luck with such approaches on ebay.  I've tried:

```
getURL(''http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords
           &SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
           &SECURITY-APPNAME=My_App_ID
           &GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US
           &RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON
           &callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords
           &REST-PAYLOAD
           &keywords=harry%20potter
           &paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3')
```

It didn't work.  I also tried:

```
 url <- "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1"
 xml.request <- "<?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords
 &SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0
 &SECURITY-APPNAME=My_App_ID
 &GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US
 &RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML
 &callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords
 &REST-PAYLOAD
 &keywords=harry%20potter
 &paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3>"

 myheader=c(Connection="close", 
 'Content-Type' = "application/xml",
 'Content-length' =nchar(xml.request))

  data =  getURL(url = url,
           postfields=xml.request,
           httpheader=myheader,
           verbose=TRUE)
```

No luck with this either.  Basically, I have no idea what I'm doing.  Can anyone help?

Comment: *What* specifically "didn't work"? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Here's a [nice blog on web scraping with APIs and R](http://blog.rolffredheim.com/2014/03/web-scraping-working-with-apis.html) that could be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure how R parses that URL but to try keeping all of your variables on the same line. (Also remember to replace My_App_ID with your)

<?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=My_App_ID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=harry%20potter&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3>

Comment: Yeah, it's wrapped for readability, and I inserted "My_App_ID" into the questions in order to avoid broadcasting my own developer credentials to the world.

Comment: @user2047457 :) just making sure that you looked at the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

I have wrapped ebay's Finding API with a new R package called `ebayr`, with a `httr::GET` call. See here: https://github.com/gsimchoni/ebayr

You'll need to get your token from https://go.developer.ebay.com/ and you're good to go.

Here's also a blog post for inspiration: http://giorasimchoni.com/2017/12/19/2017-12-19-e-is-for-elephant-the-ebayr-package/

Answer (score 0):

```
url <- 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=USER_ADD_ID&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US&keywords=macbook+refurbished&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=10'

getURL(url)

> getURL(url)
[1] "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><findItemsByKeywordsResponse xmlns=\"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services\"><ack>Success</ack><version>1.13.0</version><timestamp>2016-12-05T18:48:43.170Z</timestamp><searchResult count=\"10\"><item><itemId>152233530373</itemId><title>Apple Macbook Air 11.6\" 1.3 GHz Core i5 128 GB SSD, 4GB RAM, Yosemite- MD711LL/A</title><globalId>EBAY-US</globalId><subtitle>OS Upgraded to 10.10 Yosemite l Cosmetic Condition 8/10</subtitle><primaryCategory><categoryId>111422</categoryId><categoryName>Apple Laptops</categoryName></primaryCategory><galleryURL>http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mpUZSSnEfwJ5YOFJ8JzcmXw/140.jpg</galleryURL><viewItemURL>http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-Macbook-Air-11-6-1-3-GHz-Core-i5-128-GB-SSD-4GB-RAM-Yosemite-MD711LL-A-/152233530373</viewItemURL><productId type=\"ReferenceID\">160128184</productId><paymentMethod>PayPal</paymentMethod><autoPay>true</autoPay><location>USA</location><country>US</country><shippingInfo><shipp... <truncated>
```

Reference [Getting Started with the Finding API: Finding Items by Keywords](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/howto/gettingstarted_php_nv_xml/gettingstarted_php_nv_xml.html)